# How can I programmatically project the Z value of a z-aware feature point, using ArcObjects in .NET/C#?

Tags: arcobjects, coordinate-system, c#, .net, elevation

I discovered the following code leaves the Z coordinate of featurePt untouched:

```
// if not WGS84 project it
if (!SpatialRefsEqual(featureSpatialRef, srWgs84))
{
    // featurePt here is a Z-Aware instance of IPoint
    // use the Geometry Interface to do the actual project
    featurePt.SpatialReference = featureSpatialRef;
    featurePt.Project(srWgs84);
}
```

I see the [`IVerticalCoordinateSystem`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/VerticalCoordinateSystem_Property/002m000003mm000000/) interface but it unclear to me how to use it to do a projection.  For example, simply plugging it in via:

```
featurePt.Project(myInstanceOfIVerticalCoordinateSystem)
```

still leaves Z untouched.

It also seems like I could just write a routine to convert the Z-coordinate in the linear units of the layer to my desired linear units (meters in this case).

Is there a best practice for projecting the Z-coordinate?

**EDIT**

According to mkennedy at ESRI, ArcGIS does not provide a true vertical transformation.  If anyone knows of any outside library to vertically transform among vertical datums please let me know.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "projecting" the z-coordinate, Josh?  Normally, heights are not affected by changes of (planar) coordinate systems and therefore do not need to be changed at all when reprojecting the map coordinates.

Comment: Do both the input and the output spatialreference have a defined [vcs property?](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/VerticalCoordinateSystem_Property/002m000003mm000000/)

Comment: @whuber, I basically mean "convert" the z-coordinate, specifically the linear units, feet to meters, etc.  Part of my confusion lies in the distinction between the GIS definition of a coordinate system and the 3D graphics definition of a coordinate space (where one transforms X,Y _and_ Z).  So maybe my question doesn't make sense.  I should just look at the source linear units and convert Z to whatever units I require (again, meters...).

Comment: after speaking again with the team: simply converting Z between linear units is naive.  I truly need a vertical coordinate transformation.  For example, EGM96 to/from EGM2008, both of which could be expressed in meters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, ArcGIS 10 does not do any vertical coordinate system conversions. You can define a vertical coordinate system on a dataset, but the software isn't using the information except when defining the spatial reference (min/max z, z resolution/tolerance values). ArcScene/ArcGlobe may be checking the z units. We do plan to add vcs conversions in a future release. It has not been scheduled yet, so I cannot name a particular release or time frame.

std. disclaimer: I work for Esri.